# how to convert cpp typeid(T).hash_code() to type. (having void* destroy function PROB)

Tags: c++, hash, type-conversion, void-pointers, typeid

I'm making some Manager class like this.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

class TestMgr
{
public:
    TestMgr() = default;
    ~TestMgr() {

        for (auto iter = m_test.begin(); iter != m_test.end(); )
        {
            delete iter->second; // void* doesn't call destory function
            iter = m_test.erase(iter);
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* DoSomething()
    {
        CObject<T>* someClass = (CObject<T>*)m_test[typeid(T).hash_code()];
        if (someClass == nullptr)
        {
            m_test[typeid(T).hash_code()] = new CObject<T>();
        }
        return someClass->DoSomething();
    }

    unordered_map<size_t, void*>    m_test;
};
```

I want to save 'Template' classes in containers like 'unsorted_map' (doesn't matter with container)
And want to call a destroy function. But I have been saving the pointers by void*
So if I delete void* , destroy function don't work!
I'm will to save types, so I can convert back to its own type.
like this

```
delete (Ctest*)iter->second;
```

how can I convert back to my Template type. I need some help Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be a virtual `CObjectBase::~CObjectBase`. Now you don't need a `void*` anymore.

Comment: So you mean using a virtual classes for Template classes? ok I will try!